# Method undefined for object in java cannot be compiled and deployed

Tags: java, sockets

I am getting this error from the following:

```
public class Application extends Controller {

    public static class Result {
        public Result(String contents, Status status) {
            this.contents = contents;
            this.status = status;
        }

        public final String contents;
        public final Status status;

        // "status":{"url":"https:\/\/mtgox.com\/api\/0\/data\/ticker.php","content_type":"application\/json","http_code":200

        public static class Status {
            public final String url;
            public final String content_type;
            public final int http_code;

            public Status(String url, String content_type, int http_code) {
                this.url = url;
                this.content_type = content_type;
                this.http_code = http_code;
            }
        }
    }

    public static void index() {
        render();
    }

    public static void options(String url, final String callback) {
        response().setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        response().setHeader("Allow", "*");
        response().setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS");
        response().setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Referer, User-Agent");

        return ok();
    }
}
```

However, the url and callback is being passed on the functions. I am unsure why I am getting this error:

```
 The file /app/controllers/Application.java could not be compiled. Error 
 raised is : The method response() is undefined for the type Application
```

This is a controller file and I am unsure how to fix this syntax issue.

Comment: I am not sure what you are confused about. There is no response method that is defined inside the Application class (unless the Controller class has them). So it will complain that there is no response method. Is that the full extent of your code?

Comment: it starts out with a controller package

package controllers;

import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder;
import org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils;
import org.yaml.snakeyaml.util.UriEncoder;
import play.libs.F;
import play.libs.WS;
import play.mvc.*;

Comment: If it is inside your controller class, is it declared public, protected, private?

Comment: This is a github file I've found trying to redeploy the same app on heroku

Comment: Is this code that you have copied and pasted from somewhere? Can you link to where you found it?

Comment: https://github.com/ripper234/Whatever-Origin/blob/master/app/controllers/Application.java

Comment: And you are sure that you correctly referenced and imported all of the required dependencies into your project?

Comment: I am looking at that. The only dependency listed on the dependencies.yml file I see was play, which I used as a buildpack. But I am probably missing something if I cannot deploy it.

Comment: Missing dependency/library is most likely the culprit for your error. Make sure your import statements are the same as listed in the github page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either you have to define the response() method inside your Application class file, or you need to define them in your Controller class which your Application class inherits. You are getting that error because it cannot find any declaration of a method called response() anywhere.

And you have to make sure that any external libraries/dependencies are imported correctly.